# DB2 xmlquery how to default empty records using case statement

Tags: sql, db2

I have an XML query using a made up XML link as follows:

```
select case xmlcast(xmlquery('testpath') passing table A.column A ) as varchar(100))
when '0' then 'N'
else 'Y'
```

where Table A column A is blank the returned value gets defaulted to 'Y', but I want return the following:

```
when '0' then 'N'
when no data in column A then '*'
else 'Y'

when
```

How could I write the code to achieve replacing the blank records in column a as '*'?

Comment: Side note: `CASE` **expression** not statement. SQL knows no flow control statements at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CASE 
  WHEN tableA.columnA IS NULL THEN '*'
  WHEN xmlcast (xmlquery ('testpath') passing tableA.columnA) as varchar(100)) = '0' THEN 'N'
  ELSE 'Y'
END
```